# Laravel 5 auth always results false?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Here its my controller for logging in. the register controller works well, it creates an user to database but when i try to log in with it fails it results always false pls help.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

class loginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)

    {
        $_email = $request->input('emaillogin');
        $_password = $request->input('passwordlogin');

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $_email, 'password' => $_password])) {

            Auth::login(Auth::user());
            return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
        }
        else {
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use the built in Auth stuff?

Comment: how im supposed to do that

Comment: Read a bit on documentation in laravel 5 there is a built in auth function with registration and password, even with front end example. In laravel 5.1 the front end is gone but built in auth is still there. And also one thing the Auth::attempt checks for password with bcrypt or hash method, so check if you used hash on your password field upon registration. Also check the user data in your database to see what's saved.

Comment: I didnt use hash, but thank you anyways :)

Comment: Post your register controller and login form

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/a39jq2) here is the register controller

[link](http://prntscr.com/a39l7y) here is the login form

Comment: your form input names must match your $request ids so `$_email = $request->input('email');` since name of your email field in form is `email` also you must use bcrypt on password field upon registration, check my answer for more details .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the comment and i just tested it on my local pc, maybe it's wrong to you but for me it doesn't work if i use plain password save in database, here's my register file

```
    protected function create(array $data)
{
    $activation_code = str_random(60);
    $user = User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'activation_code' => $activation_code
    ]);

    if ($user->save()) {
        $data = array(
        'name' => $user->username,
        'code' => $activation_code,
        );
        \Mail::queue('emails.activate', $data, function($message) use ($user) {
        $message->to($user->email)->subject('Thank you for registering. Please activate your account!');
        });
    }

    return $user;
}
```

you see i have crypted password

```
'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
```

and if i test it just with:

```
'password' =>$data['password'],
```

The registration works but authentication fails because password must be encripted you should also remove `Auth::login(Auth::user());` that is not necessary

```
 if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $_email, 'password' => $_password])) { 

  return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');

}
```

This happens on my site when i don't use bcrypt on password in registration controller and try to login later

```
Whoops! There were some problems with your input.

These credentials do not match our records.
```

Also what i have seen from our login form inputs are not `emaillogin` and `passwordlogin` they are just `email` and `password`

Comment: I bcrypt the password in the registerController and still i get the authentication fail. Yes and the login controller are the same request from input. Would you mind to get my email and try to fix this with teamviewer im begginer in L5.

Answer (score 2):

`Auth::attempt` logs user into your application if passed, no need for second authentication

```
 if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $_email, 'password' => $_password])) { 

      return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');

 } else { 

     return redirect()->guest('/login'); 

 }
```

Comment: `return` was missing in `if` block.

Comment: yes i saw that but still. i saw many people having problem with this. Is this a laravel error ?

Comment: Let's troubleshoot .... Replace return redirect()->intended('/dashboard'); with dd('hey I am in'); and try again tell me the result